# Geometry nodes connection between values

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

[image: How to connect both nodes?]

Hello, I don't understand why connecting the random value output and any of the grey inputs on the right doesn't match. What do I need to add? Thanks!

Comment: The round inputs/outputs is „kind of“ only one value, but the rhombus show that these are more values. That’s why you cannot connect them.

Comment: What do you want the random value for?  GN 3.0 doesn't really have a way to generate a single random float.

Answer (score 10):

The way this seems to normally be done is to drive the *Random Value*'s *ID* socket with an integer.  This changes the *Value* output socket to output a single value:

[image: Using an integer to drive the Random Value]

One of the not-well-documented features of 3.0 Geometry Nodes is that some nodes output type depends on their inputs.  In this case, an 'ordinary' ID would lead to a field output (the diamond shape) but forcing an int into the ID socket changes the output type to a single float value.